# Angular 2 router pass parameters and get them when changes

Tags: parameters, angular, onchange, router

How I can pass some parameters to my rotes, like was in the old router?

Old

```
@RouteConfig([
  new Route({path: '/home', component: HomeCmp, name: 'HomeCmp' })
])
```

New

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/login', component: Component}
])
```

and then get them in subscribe for changes?

```
 export class AppComponent {

        public constructor(private router: Router) {

            this.router.changes.subscribe((x) => {
                console.log(x);
            });
```

I mean in old angular there was a state and we could attach events `onBefore` ect and get the current state. How actually this would work here. `this.router.changes.subscribe` - it's triggering the change, but don't give any information about it - `x` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

No parameter exists in the subscribe anymore. You need to use the location service to check the current route:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(router:Router, private location:Location) {
    router.changes.subscribe(() => this.routeChanged());
  }

  private routeChanged():void {
    var path:string = this.location.path();
    console.log("Path:" + path);
  }
}
```